# How can I POST from a chrome extension to a flask-security endpoint?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, flask, oauth-2.0, google-chrome-app

- I have a web application built with python flask using flask-security for user authentication.
- I want the users of the application to securely POST data from a chrome extension (their chrome.tabs.getSelected url) to an authenticated page in the web application.
- This will pass extension data (their current url) to the web application and store it in their user profile on the web application.

How can I accomplish the above with a minimal amount of code?

Comment: I suppose it is too broad a question, I will try to narrow it so it fits the guidelines now.

Comment: I found the best solution to be flask-cors and flask-security. Be sure to CSRF protect credential endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on the subject, but I built a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverflow-inbox-notif/ndeljpkeimafgobechdfejolnpgcjomi?hl=en-US) which used oAuth2 to connect to the StackOverflow API... so I'm going to give you some information about that approach.

As you point out, Chrome has an API for [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity), and specifically I used the `launchWebAuthFlow()` method. (Example [here](https://github.com/arthurakay/StackOverflow-Notifications/blob/master/background/background.js#L46))

In the callback, I save a reference to the returned token and then use that on every request to the StackOverflow API. It's pretty painless, assuming your endpoint already has the oAuth2 workflow in place.

Comment: Thank you for posting the example. There's not a lot of information re: flask<->chrome extension specifically, so hopefully this will be a resource.

That will be really helpful for understanding the client-side if I use the oauth2 option, but I'm still concerned about the server doing implicit flows securely to/from a javascript client.